# Events not being logged in with AppEventsLogger

Tags: ios, react-native, analytics, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to use react-native-fbsdk for Facebook analytics. When I go to the events debugging page to check if it works, I can see a couple events like `App Activation` and `App Installs` and other stuff like `Completed App Session`. Of these, I'm manually logging `App Activation` whereas the rest is I think the sdk provides by default. 
The problem is, it's not logging many other custom events that I'm trying to log.
How do I debug this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you send the custom events, are you setting the `page_scoped_user_id` correctly? Here is a raw JSON cutom event, per [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/bots-for-messenger).

```
{ 
  url : "https://graph.facebook.com/<app_id>/activities",
  form: {
    event: 'CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS',
    custom_events: JSON.stringify([{
      _eventName: "fb_mobile_purchase",
      _valueToSum: 55.22,
      _fb_currency: 'USD'
    }]),
    advertiser_tracking_enabled: 0,
    application_tracking_enabled: 0,
    extinfo: JSON.stringify(['mb1']),
    page_id: <page_id>,
    page_scoped_user_id: recipientId
  }
}
```

The last value, `recipientId`, is misleading. If you want to log something the user sent, you would want to log the `senderId` property of that incoming message.